# How to convert time as per Timezone selection in android?

Tags: android, datetime, android-studio, timezone, android-timepicker

My Application downloading shopping details.
Example :
Shopping details downloaded at 5 :30 London time.
Now, change any other timezone, so convert downloaded time s per the selected timezone.
Timezone is changing from settings under Date/time.
***How to programmatically achieve this*** ?
so **how to convert the downloaded time as per the timezone selection** ?

Comment: TimeZone.getDefault() will give u the device timezone.

Comment: @Raghvendra : okay, it will give me the current timezone, now convert already downloaded time to that timezon selection. so how that is calculated ?

Comment: Can u post the sample time which you have downloaded. I mean the format of that time.?

Comment: @Raghvendra - e.g. time = Downloaded time = 08:15 - as per London Timezone, now select IST timezone so now (GMT + 5:30) that time should be converted. so how could this achieve here ?

Comment: @Swift how you achieve this i have same requirement can you post your ans?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

I assume you have downloaded the shopping details at 12:00 PM London time. I am using HH assuming that you are using 24hr format. If you want to convert that to device default time zone, set the timezone using DateFormat & format the existing time.

**TimeZone.getDefault()** which gives the device default timezone.

```
 try {
       DateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
       utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

       Date date = utcFormat.parse("12:00");

       DateFormat deviceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
       deviceFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault()); //Device timezone

       String convertedTime = deviceFormat.format(date);

} catch(Exception e){

}
```

Comment: Thanks, It's useful now.

Comment: @Swift glad! that helped:)

Answer (score 0):

no, there are no APIs for changing time or timezone.. It is not possible to change the phone's timezone programmatically.

Comment: No, i am asking. Is there any code snippet where can we fetch current timezone of the device and convert downloaded time as per timezone selection ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Raghavendra solution, this can be a portable method as follows:

```
/**
 * converts GMT date and/or time with a certain pattern into Local Device TimeZone
 * Example of dateTimePattern:
 *      "HH:mm",
 *      "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
 *      "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
 * Ex of dateTimeGMT:
 *      "12:00",
 *      "15:23",
 *      "2019-02-22 09:00:21"
 * This assumes 24hr format
 */
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
private String getDeviceDateTimeFromGMT(String dateTimePattern, String dateTimeGMT) {
    try {
        DateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dateTimePattern);
        utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); // convert from GMT TimeZone

        Date date = utcFormat.parse(dateTimeGMT);

        DateFormat deviceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dateTimePattern);
        deviceFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault()); // Device TimeZone

        return deviceFormat.format(date);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
getDeviceDateTimeFromGMT("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", "2019-02-22 16:07"); 
getDeviceDateTimeFromGMT("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "2019-02-22 16:07:13"); 
getDeviceDateTimeFromGMT("H:mm", "16:07");
```